What should I keep in mind when traveling to the Costa Blanca in December 2024 after the storms and floods of October 2024?
I'm planning on a 3.5 week vacation to the Costa Blanca from mid December to early January. I'm taking the plane to Alicante, where my parents will pick me up for a car trip to Calpé. I've spent 29 of my last 30 winters in Calpé, the only exception being during the COVID-19 Pandemic in 2020 when the Communidad Valencia had closed their borders for all non-essential travel. As you can probably tell, this vacation is important to me, and I really do not want to cancel it unless I am forced to because Valencia closed the borders again.
The past week or so, Valencia has been hit by calamitous amounts of rain, with extreme floods causing extensive damage and over a hundred casualties. Bridges have collapsed, roads have been blocked up with wrecked cars and massive amounts of mud, and the main railroad between Madrid and Valencia has been destroyed.
That being said, based on rain maps and webcam footage from the region, Calpé appears to have missed the brunt of the rain, and the roads between Alicante and Calpé seem to be open according to Google and Waze.
I am currently operating under the assumption that my vacation will happen like usual, but I would like to know if there are things I should be aware of with regards to travel to this region in light of the recent floods.

Your question reads as if your parents are already in the area? If so, what is their take on the situation and advice on things to be aware of?

@Traveller My parents leave late November. They're not there yet, but are planning on going.

About Costa Blanca, so not too norths: Probably by then, it would be nearly business as usual. You may expect not all trains (routes) will run, but that should not affect you. Also roads: they may be some detours, or reduced speed limits and working areas. Maybe some houses and parking will be affected by floods (underground), but I would not expect much direct impact.
In few days I would check the Alicante Airports, to see if flights are normal (including holidays flights). Now it is too early, we may not get the idea if people are coming, or just some soft evacuation of tourists. Then you can check official sites. Also now it may be too early: they may have better thing to do, then updating sites (but local newspaper should have more updated informations). And it seems your parents are there, so they may get more information.
Usually, a part for the emergency part (early response), the rest of works will be done by professional, so anything that can bring normal life (so tourist) is welcome (but if it affect local authorities badly, so high traffic on affected zone, but it doesn't seem your case).
But it is too early. Wait one week to have more information.
